# Traverse object tree and print properties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to traverse an object tree and print out all the properties in the object, including the nested properties, using recursion. Here is my code but it is stuck in the loop and I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
var data = {
  person: {
    firstName: 'Mary'
  },
  color: 'blue'
};

function walk(root) {
  for(var i in root) {
    if(root.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      console.log(i);
      if ( root[i] !== null && root[i] !== undefined && typeof(root[i] == 'object') ) {
        walk(root[i]);
      }    
    }
  }
}

walk(data);
```

Comment: Open debugger and find it out.

Comment: `typeof(root[i] == 'object')` - uh, are you sure there?

Comment: @Bergi let them learn how to use debugger ;-) But yep, I realise that in 10 seconds it will be an answer posted already.

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure about that. I'm not quite sure how to check if a properties value is an object or some other type.

Comment: @Mdd try to read what `typeof(root[i] == 'object')` expression does aloud. Literally, read it and evaluate it as if you were a JS engine.

Comment: @Mdd `if(root.hasOwnProperty(i))` is redundant. You are saying forEach key in object then next line you say if key exists in object.

Comment: @SamuelToh it's not, please check the function documentation.

Comment: @zerkms: It should still be dropped, as we only expect objects with own enumerable properties. And if we don't, it should be replaced with `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`

Comment: @Bergi that's paranoid, but point taken. PS: or use `for-of`

Comment: @zerkms thanks so much!  I didn't realize that the () did not need to come immediately after the `typeof` until I stared at with a `debug` statement for a few minutes.  Thank you!

Comment: @Mdd thanks for making my day: if I turned someone to use debugger more frequently (or at all), then my mission here is successful :-)

Comment: @zerkms for sure! It's been quite a while since I used `typeof`.  Thanks again for reminding me about the console dev tools.

Comment: @Mdd Or check out Webstorm it is pretty good. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** This solution has been updated to transverse nested array.

Just want to have a closure on this problem which is why I took some time to solve it, even thou OP could possibly be playing with his debugging tool now (see comments).

My approach to this problem was solve it using the `instanceof` API. 
**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

That way I don't have to put in extra codes to do those long winded checks like

1. `root.hasOwnProperty(i)`
2. `if ( root[i] !== null && root[i] !== undefined && typeof(root[i] == 'object') )`

**Example:**

```
var data = {
  person: {
    firstName: 'Mary',
    likes: {
      food: "apple",
      drinks: "water",
      d: null,
      x : {
        y: "z",
        ddd: [
          { bbb: "lol"},
          { PPP: "lol2"}
        ]
      },
      o: undefined
    }
  },
  color: 'blue'
};

function walk(root) {
  for (let property in root) {
    console.log(property);
    if (root[property] instanceof Array)
        root[property].forEach(item => { walk(item); });
    else if (root[property] instanceof Object)
      walk(root[property]);
    // Extend else if statement to handle customize structures appropriately.
  }
}

walk(data);
```

**Output:**

```
person
firstName
likes
food
drinks
d
x
y
ddd
e
bbb
PPP
o
color
```

Comment: It doesn't work for objects that don't inherit from `Object`, though (like `Object.create(null)` or cross-frame objects)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing this out. I will go through the solution again. I think it will also not work if we have a key that has a value of an array where the array consists of more objects. Example: `ddd: [ { bbb: "lol"} ]`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve my own issue with the help of the console debugger. I was not aware of using instanceof like that though. Thanks!

Comment: @Mdd - I have updated the solution to handle nested arrays. I have given Bergi's scenario a thought and I think it is really a corner case here. If you have something that is not inherited from `Object` then you'll have to extend the `instanceOf statements to handle it. Then depending on the structure of this custom object you'll have to handle it appropriately. @Bergi do you think this is a fair comment?